# Uncheck filter to exclude values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter out (uncheck) a few of the items.

For example, values to be excluded are 10 and 11. There are an unknown amount of values in the column.

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$AM$31570").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following if you want to exclude values 10 and 11 from your filter:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$AM$31570").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="<>10", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>11"
```